# Python: Unicode source file adds spaces (actually null bytes) between characters

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, decoding

I am a newbie. However, I managed to extract some lines from a txt-file (unicode) and write them in another file.

```
lines = InFile.readlines()
OutFile.writelines(lines[3:])
```

It is working but (I believe) due to a coding issue there is a space added between each character in the output file. 
Example of a result:

```
2 0 1 3 - 1 2 - 2 3 ; ; 3 6 0 . 3 7 
2 0 1 3 - 1 2 - 2 4 ; ; 0 . 0 0
```

Lines in the source file:

```
2013-12-23;;360.37
2013-12-24;;0.00
```

If I save the txt source file as ANSI before running the script, I receive the correct results. However, as the source file is delivered automatically as Unicode by another software, it is not practical to change that every time manually. I read through a lot of other coding/encoding/decoding questions. But I am completely lost and don't know how I can fix that issue. Which is the correct command? At which place in the script? Or am I completely wrong and it doesn't have anything to do with a coding issue?

Comment: How was `OutFile` opened? What version of Python are you using, and how are you reading the file to see the 'spaces' between the characters?

Comment: A file is never "Unicode" - it can use a variety of encodings that can be *decoded*  to Unicode strings (like UTF-8, UTF-16-LE, UTF-16-BE, UTF-32...), but the file itself consists of simple bytes.

Comment: I suspect the OP is being misled by certain Microsoft products which offer options like "save as Unicode". And use UTF-16-LE as we see here. Which is not to say you're wrong.

Comment: Windows adds junk nulls to any text file you edit, so instead of 'text content' you always get 't e x t   c o n t e n t ' when opening the file with any decent editor. Never followed that logic.

Answer (score 13):

I'm fairly certain that your input file is UTF-16 encoded, and the spaces you're seeing are actually null bytes.

Try

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-16") as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
```

and see if the problem persists.

Comment: You were right, it seems to be UTF-16. I tried your suggestion but couldn't make it work. Probably I made a mistake. However, I browsed a view other options and it is working well with: `InFile = codecs.open(sys.argv[1], "r", "utf-16")` For beginners like me: don't forget to include `import codecs`at the beginning. Thanks for your help. Saved my day.

Comment: @user3037270, don't forget to accept this answer since your day was saved. :)

Comment: I'll just add that you don't want to iterate through a file encoded in utf-16 by lines ending in linefeed. Doing so will seemingly screw up every line past the first because the strings are broken up after the single linefeed byte and not the two that are required for utf-16. That leaves an extra byte hanging at the beginning of every line and fouls up the decoding. I ran into this when iterating through a utf-16-le encoded file downloaded via urllib.request.urlopen() and trying to decode each line in turn. You have to decode the whole response at once, or at least be smarter about iterating.