# Python2.7 Unicode adding spaces to list of strings when reading file

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using python 2.7 and I'm basically having the same problem as the guy here(only this did not work for me): [Python: Unicode source file adds spaces (actually null bytes) between characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249832/python-unicode-source-file-adds-spaces-between-characters)

```
import os
import codecs


def test():
    LogFile = 'C:\\Temp\\blankity\\file.log'
    output = os.popen('copy ' + LogFile + ' ' + 'temp.txt')

    with codecs.open('temp.txt', 'a+', encoding="utf-8") as fileContents:
        for line in fileContents:
            print line
        fileContents.close()
        os.remove('temp.txt')
```

**File Contents**

```
  : SUCCESS
```

is actually outputting as:

```
   :   S U C C E S S
```

I need it to output as:

```
  : SUCCESS
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check the encoding of your source file. Are you sure that it contains UTF-8 encoded data, or is it perhaps UTF-16 encoded (default on windows). Post the results of `repr(open('temp.txt').read())`

Comment: Been trying utf-16 with the BOM error. But when I changed it to utf-16le, it looks like it's working now. Thanks :)