# Bytes after every letter. How to get rid of them

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is my Python showing such a weird pattern when I open my .txt file and how can I load it in normally (I use Python 3.5)? In other words, I want to get rid of the \x00 after every letter that I have.

```
In:
f = open(file_path, encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
read_data = f.read()
read_data[0:100]

Out:
'H\x00i\x00e\x00r\x00b\x00i\x00j\x00 \x00w\x00i\x00l\x00 \x00i\x00k\x00 \x00u\x00 \x00m\x00e\x00d\x00e\x00d\x00e\x00l\x00e\x00n\x00,\x00 \x00d\x00a\x00t\x00 \x00i\x00k\x00 \x00m\x00i\x00j\x00n\x00 \x00s\x00p\x00a\x00a\x00r\x00r\x00e\x00k\x00e\x00n\x00'
```

An example of the file when I open it in my Notepad:

```
Hierbij wil ik u mededelen, dat ik mijn spaarrekening onder nummer __LARGENUMBER__ wil beëindigen.                                                                          
Graag maak ik van de gelegenheid [... row continues]                    
Hierbij verzoek ik u de volgende rekening op te [... row continues]
```

Comment: Your file's encoding is UTF-16 (which is the default on Windows), whereas you open it as UTF-8

Comment: What file encoding is Notepad++ using? You should use the same one when you open it in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Unicode source file adds spaces (actually null bytes) between characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249832/python-unicode-source-file-adds-spaces-actually-null-bytes-between-characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your text most likely simply isn't encoded using UTF-8, but UTF-16 or maybe UCS-2. That means all those NULs are in fact part of the character code before. Verifying it might require a character that uses the second byte, like a BOM or perhaps that ë. Try using `utf_16_le` as encoding when reading the file.

Comment: It was UTF-16. Thanks!